# Getting minimum three values in inner dictionary (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, dictionary, key, min

My dictionary values are like this:

`manhattan[imagePath1][imagePath2] = img2manhattan`.

So how can I get keys of minimum three values as list? ( Among imagePath2 keys)

(I want to get key of first smallest value + key of second smallest value + key of third smallest value as list.)

Comment: Is that the minimum for each inner dictionary, or the minimum across all inner dictionaries?

Comment: See [**`heapq.nsmallest`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest)

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs and outputs? See how to create an [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way :

```
d = dict(manhattan[imagePath1][imagePath2])
min_keys = []
for i in xrange(3):
    min_keys.append(min(d,key=d.get))
    del d[min_keys[-1]]
```

after this min_keys contain what you need.

Comment: this way deleting min values respectively as I understand it and I dont want to do any changes at dictionary

Comment: Yes my bad ! I'm editing my answer so that the values are deleted only in a temporary dictionnary and not in the original one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [**`heapq.nsmallest`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
import heapq

manhattan = {'path1_a': {'path2_a': 1,
                         'path2_b': 5},
             'path1_b': {'path2_c': 3,
                         'path2_d': 7},
             'path1_c': {'path2_e': 4,
                         'path2_f': 9}}

print heapq.nsmallest(3,
                      ((path1, path2, value)
                       for path1, path2s in manhattan.items()
                       for path2, value in path2s.items()),
                      key=lambda (path1, path2, value): value)
```

Output:

```
[('path1_a', 'path2_a', 1),
 ('path1_b', 'path2_c', 3),
 ('path1_c', 'path2_e', 4)]
```

Comment: Thx for sample but I want get "path2_a", "path2_c", "path2_e" respectively as a list. (the smallest three value in the manhattan[key] which the "key" iterates in path1_a, path1_b ... )

Answer (score 1):

You Should provide some sample input and expected output, If possible please edit your question with these information, Here is tried with @peter sample data:

> One line solution:

```
#data from @peter
manhattan = {'path1_a': {'path2_a': 1,
                         'path2_b': 5},
             'path1_b': {'path2_c': 3,
                         'path2_d': 7},
             'path1_c': {'path2_e': 4,
                         'path2_f': 9}}

print(["".join([key for key, value in item.items() if value == min(item.values())])for item in manhattan.values()])
```

output:

```
['path2_e', 'path2_a', 'path2_c']
```

> Detailed solution:

```
final_list=[]
for item in manhattan.values():
    for key,value in item.items():
        if value == min(item.values()):
            final_list.append(key)

print(final_list)
```

output:

```
['path2_c', 'path2_e', 'path2_a']
```